# epoch time comparison bsd / MacOSX

Tags: macos, bash, date

This should be obvious to all but me,

I have a file full of epoch timestamps and I'm trying to get the records from the last 7 days.

So I tried this in my mac:

```
PAST=$(gdate -d "7 days ago" +%s)
if [ $timeval -gt  $PAST ]; then
  do stuff 
 fi
```

Example erroneous output:

```
TS from data, Human fr data, TS from $PAST, Human from $PAST
1419981977690,Tue Jun  9 06 14 50 PST 46967,1421129827,Mon Jan 12 22 17 07 PST 2015
1419400311440,Thu Jan  2 00 17 20 PST 46949,1421129827,Mon Jan 12 22 17 07 PST 2015
1420341489480,Fri Oct 30 06 38 00 PST 46978,1421129827,Mon Jan 12 22 17 07 PST 2015
1421232275040,Thu Jan 22 07 04 00 PST 47007,1421129827,Mon Jan 12 22 17 07 PST 2015
```

Comment: Note that `gdate` (presumably meaning GNU `date`) is not standard on Mac OS X.

Comment: Correct ... I installed with homebrew.

Comment: How are you reading this file?

Comment: Sometimes curl and pipe or sometimes direct read.

Comment: I wish you had written a self answer, or edited the given answer to be more clear what exactly your solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamps in your file are in milliseconds, not seconds. Divide them by 1000.

Comment: added: TIMEVAL=$(($timeval/1000)) and if [ "$TIMEVAL" -gt  "$PAST" ] ... no dice

Comment: fixed ... it is working now thanks to that small oversite which you helped me see. I was also pretty printing the $timeval as opposed to $TIMEVAL which confused me.