# Is there a straight-forward way to convert millisecond based timestamps on MacOs?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, date

[EpochConverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) turns a timestamp value like `1586775709496` into `Monday, April 13, 2020 11:01:49.496 AM`.

Unfortunately, the `date` tool on MacOs expects *seconds*, not milliseconds, and gives a wrong year:

```
> date -r 1586775709496
Thu Dec  2 15:24:56 CET 52252
```

This existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038931/epoch-time-comparison-bsd-macosx) only explains the obvious: you can divide by 1000 (cut of the trailing 3 digits) and the built-in `date` tool will work.

But: that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a "straightforward" way to turn such millisecond based timestamps into "human readable" *including* the milliseconds. Are there ways to achieve that?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to install GNU `date`, which supports a `%N` format for nanoseconds: e.g., `date +"%a %b %d %T.%N" --date @$(echo "scale=3; 1586775709496/1000" | bc)` outputs `Mon Apr 13 07:01:49.496000000`. (Unfortunately, there's no straightforward way to just add `%N` to the default format; you have to recreate it in full.)

Answer (score 5):

```
timestamp=1586775709496
ms=$(( $timestamp % 1000 ))
echo "$(date -r  $(( $timestamp / 1000 )) +"%a, %b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S").$ms"
Mon, Apr 13, 2020 12:01:49.496
```

you can edit the date format string to get exactly the result you need.

Comment: Whatever the other answer was it's been deleted. I'll add the ms into an edit version.

Comment: Yes, this definitely looks better. And I agree: it doesnt add dependencies to have brew/gdate.

Answer (score 3):

With gnu date I believe that would be:

```
$ a=1586775709496
$ LC_ALL=C date -u --date=@"$((a/1000)).$(printf "%03d" $((a%1000)))" +"%A, %B %2d, %Y %H:%M:%S.%3N %p"
Monday, April 13, 2020 11:01:49.496 PM
```

The `%3N` is something that GNU date supports and it prints only milliseconds.

I guess because the last 3 characters of input are just in the output, you could just input them where they should be, removing the need for `%N` extension:

```
$ a=1586775709496;
$ LC_ALL=C date -u --date=@"$((a/1000))" +"%A, %B %2d, %Y %H:%M:%S.$(printf "%03d" $((a%1000))) %p"
```

Comment: Addendum: in order to get this working, one need the GNU date. Which can be installed via "brew install coreutils", and then you got a gdate command.

Comment: I'm intrigued: Do you consider installing a non-standard (for macOS) function to be 'straightforward'?

Comment: @Lorccan I didnt say that. But: when you already have brew, and brew coreutils, then well, it is straightforward.